# Does the (Ragnersson) mean (Son of Ragnar)?

Tags: vikings

What is the meaning of **Ragnarsson**, does it mean *the son of Ragnar* or it is a stand-alone name?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragnarsson - these days it's both.

Comment: In the case of Sweden at least, a soldier which went by the name Johannes Erikson (Johannes, son of Erik) could because his company/unit had many Erikson adopt or design a family name.  Soldiers who got enobled designed a name for themself and their family. So did farmer's sons which became priests.

Comment: take a look at how they name sons and daughters in iceland today.  for ex. Thor Magnus has a son named Ragnar Magnusson, and a daughter named Thura Thorsdottir.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, both.  In traditional Norse culture, it's "son of", e.g. Leif Erikson was the son of Erik the Red (discoverer of Greenland).  Most western cultures at some point converted such names to a family name, thus you would have generations of Eriksons.  But Iceland keeps the traditional Norse system (at least partly).  Women take the '-dottir" (daughter) suffix, instead of "-son" (or sometimes "-sen"), sometimes with the mother's name rather than the father's.

(Note that Russian names also work somewhat similarly, with a patronymic middle name, e.g. Nikita Sergeyevich Khrushchev was the son of Sergei Khrushchev.)

Comment: And if you happen to be from Minnesota you will realize Ander, Peter and John had *very* large families ( many *Andersons, Petersons, Johnsons...* )

Comment: Just ask [Gunnar Gunarsson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-OOpZitfd0).   Anyway, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patronymic) is incredibly common.  "son" is just more noticeable in that it is so close to the modern English word for son.

Comment: @Gort the Robot: Many English names also have -son endings, I think more or less independently of the Norse.

Comment: It's hard to disentangle the two cultures given the Norse influence on the English language.   Consider that quintessential English surname "[Nelson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelson_(surname)#:~:text=Nelson%20is%20a%20surname%2C%20also,from%20the%20nickname%20%22Nell%22.)"